# Any linux OS shuts down once the AC adapter is plugged in

Tags: shutdown, charging

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a 250 g4 Hp laptop, the OS runs perfectly when the charger isn't plugged in, once i connect the charger to the laptop, it shuts down. The same thing even happened when i was installing it several times until i removed the charger. Should i try another distribution or it's my laptop?

**Update**: i tried different distributions like mint, fedora and all of them seem to have the same problem.

I'm using dual boot with windows 10 and the charger works fine.

Comment: Try booting your laptop **after** the AC adapter is plugged in for awhile. Any change?

Comment: No changes. The os keeps on shutting before the login screen appears.

Comment: Have you tried another charger to eliminate it as the possible cause of the system shutting down?  If it does it with another charger, then you might be looking at a possible bad power connector inside the laptop or a possible bad motherboard.  This does not sound like a software issue, or at least a software issue that I have ever heard of.

Comment: The charger works fine when I'm using windows. I doubt it could be the problem.

Comment: You should have add that to your question that when you try it in Windows on the same laptop it does not power off.  That is really important.  My comment was based off of your present question.

Comment: Not a fix but this may temporarily help till a solution is found. ```sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target``` Re-Enable ```sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it still shuts down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for my Dell Inspiron running Ubuntu, which has the same problem you described: Close the laptop, plug in the adapter, wait a few seconds, reopen the lid. You're presented with the locked screen.

Perhaps this isn't a "solution" because the laptop shouldn't reboot on plugging in the power. But it may be a helpful workaround.

Comment: You solution works despite it turns off the wifi and i need to restart the network manager. Also i found out that when I'm running clementine and plugging the charger, it doesn't shut down. It's wired, but i can have longer sessions on my IDEs now, thanks.